# Ошибка 'list' is not callable без видимых на то причин

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я столкнулся с проблемой...
Я пытаюсь написать подобие линукса на питоне, и для реализации терминала я сделал такую функцию:
Выдаёт TypeError: type 'list' is not callable
Я пошарился по стаку, и так и не понял почему это может происходить...

Вот код:

```
def path():
    for w in term:
        if read:
            path.append(w)
        else:
            if w == '//':
                read = True
    path = ''.join(path)
path = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, вы потом `path` ещё и вызываете? Примерно так:

```
def path():
   pass

path = []

path()
```

Вы уж определитесь, либо `path` это список, либо функция. В `Python` нельзя так делать, чтобы одинаково назывались разные сущности, переменные в питоне хранят всё подряд, им без разницы - число, функция, итератор... Поэтому если вы в переменную `path` сначала определили функцию, а потом туда же положили список, то там будет список, а про функцию вашу питон уже забыл.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

у вас в приведённой функции

1. отсутствует `return` - функция ничего не выдает (значит выдает `None`)
2. переменная `path` отсутствует - это не VBA чтобы так возвращать результат
3. `join` работает со списком строк, а `path = ''.join(path)` тут никакого списка строк нет

Comment: проблема в последней строке, переменная в которой лежит функцию меняется на список